# You gave us a visitor for the node type "ForAwaitStatement" but it's not a valid type

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I'm getting the following error from a few different libraries in my project, after adding the `"stage-2"` preset to my `.babelrc`. (Thats my assumption atm)

e.g. from the DatePicker class in React Native:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePickerAndroid/DatePickerAndroid.android.js: You gave us a visitor for the node type "ForAwaitStatement" but it's not a valid type
```

How can I resolve this error?

I'm using React Native 0.31 and

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.17.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I too ran into this. Solved by updating my babel-core version by changing the entry in package.json to the latest (at the time of this writing)

```
// package.json
...
"babel-core": "6.17.0",
...
```

then running

```
rm -r node_modules/babel* && npm i
```

Comment: I actually solved this by removing `"stage-2"` from my `.babelrc`, turns out I didn't actually need it as React Native supports what I needed. Marking this as the answer as it seems complete.

Comment: Even after updating I still had problems. Solved by flushing all babel related modules `rm -r node_modules/babel* && npm i`.

Comment: Same issue as @greenimpala. Updating didnt work. Needed to flush all babel modules and reinstall

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue after updating babel-core and some babel plugins. In my case it was fixed by updating babel-cli (globally installed with npm), which was a few versions behind and not using the right babel-core version.

Comment: it was failing still with `"babel-core": "6.17.0",` as suggested in the other answer, upgrading babel-cli did the trick.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this after an `npm update`, struggled for several hours to find a fix, but ultimately solved it via `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. I hate npm.

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue is caused by a lower version babel-types, so the solution is just:

```
npm install babel-types
```

or a clean npm install:

```
git clean -fdx
npm install
```

Comment: This worked for me — bumping all versions didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your babel-cli is out of date, you might get the same error. Try updateing babel-cli using `npm install babel-cli -g` or update your local `babel-cli` and reference it in your package.json scripts.
Also do `npm i -D babel-plugin-transform-runtime` and add `"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]` to your .babelrc

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar situation as @Thomas; a globally installed version of babel-cli which was behind. I can recommend not installing it globally, instead running babel through npm scripts.

Local install:

`npm install babel-cli --save-dev`

In your npm [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts):

`"babel": "babel script.js"`