# How to Resolve Error: "You gave us a visitor for the node type TSSatisfiesExpression but it's not a valid type"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, babeljs, storybook

something happens to babel, it can't compile my storybook code

I'm trying to assemble a boilerplate with storybook and nextjs

I did a search and couldn't find a solution to this problem, if anyone can help I would be grateful

This is the error I get when trying to build

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types ..warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
> [PWA] Compile client (static)
> [PWA] Auto register service worker with: /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next-pwa/register.js
> [PWA] Service worker: /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/.next/sw.js
> [PWA]   url: /sw.js
> [PWA]   scope: /
> [PWA] Compile server
> [PWA] Compile server
info  - Using external babel configuration from /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/.babelrc
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/_app.tsx
Error: [BABEL] /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/src/pages/_app.tsx: You gave us a visitor for the node type TSSatisfiesExpression but it's not a valid type
    at verify (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:397612)
    at Function.explode (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:396515)
    at /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:49254
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:79767)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717268)
    at Function.sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:715284)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:80263)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)

./src/pages/_document.tsx
Error: [BABEL] /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/src/pages/_document.tsx: You gave us a visitor for the node type TSSatisfiesExpression but it's not a valid type
    at verify (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:397612)
    at Function.explode (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:396515)
    at /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:49254
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:79767)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717268)
    at Function.sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:715284)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:80263)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)

./src/pages/index.tsx
Error: [BABEL] /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/src/pages/index.tsx: You gave us a visitor for the node type TSSatisfiesExpression but it's not a valid type
    at verify (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:397612)
    at Function.explode (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:396515)
    at /home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:49254
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:79767)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:717268)
    at Function.sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:715284)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1:80263)
    at sync (/home/crepszz/Desktop/boilerplate/boilerplate/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:716601)


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

//_app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import GlobalStyles from '../styles/global'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>React Avançado</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="A simple project starter to work with Typescript"
        />
      </Head>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

//__document.tsx

```
import Document, {
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
  DocumentContext
} from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: [initialProps.styles, sheet.getStyleElement()]
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

//index.tsx

```
import Main from 'components/Main'

export default function Home() {
  return <Main />
}
```

//next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true
}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    forceSwcTransforms: true
  }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    disable: !isProd
  }
})
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",    
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watch",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*": [
      "yarn lint --fix",
      "yarn test --findRelatedTests --bail"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.24",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.41.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.41.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.2.2",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.1.1",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build failed because of webpack errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74230711/build-failed-because-of-webpack-errors)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `yarn.lock` file and `node-modules` folder and then run `yarn` again to install dependencies.
Try starting local server after that.
This worked for me.
For more info you can check https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12893

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot, spent more than two days to resolve this issue, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following to your `next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  // ...
  experimental: {
    forceSwcTransforms: true,
  }
}
```

Please note that this is an experimental feature, and it may break at any time.